# How do I avoid closing an InputStream passed to my method that I wrap in Reader streams?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm creating a Java method that accepts a single `InputStream` as an argument. For the convenience of working with a character-based stream, I wrap the provided `InputStream`  at the start of the method implementation as follows:

```
public void doStuff(InputStream inStream) {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
   ...
}
```

Since the `InputStream` (`inStream`) is passed to my method, I don't want to close it ... as I think that should be the responsibility of the client calling my method (is this assumption correct?). However, I do think that I should close the `BufferedReader` that I created; but in doing so, I believe it will automatically close all the other composed streams including the `inStream`.

Does anyone see a way for me to close the `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` that I created while not closing the `InputStream` passed to my method? Maybe there is a way to make a copy of the provided `InputStream` before I wrap it? Thanks

Comment: You are aware that the unwrapped stream will be pretty much useless?

Comment: You should supply a specific `Charset` when creating an `InputStreamReader` rather than ignoring it and letting the platform default get used.

Comment: Tom, would you clarify what you mean by "the unwrapped stream will be pretty much useless"?

Comment: After doing some testing, it appears wrapping the `InputStream` in the other stream classes is a bad idea if I intend to leave the provided `InputStream` open when the method completes. It seems when the `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader` go out of scope at the end of the method, the `InputStream` is cleared. That is, even if bytes are remaining on the `InputStream` at the time the method ends, calling `read()` on the `InputStream` immediately after the method returns -1.

Comment: You are right, it is a bad idea to use a `BufferedReader` on a stream you want to read from later: The underlying input stream may be exhausted by the buffer used in the `BufferedReader`, even if you don't use all of the buffered input. There is no way to push back the unused buffer (although there is a `PushbackInputStream`, you would not know how much to push back).

Comment: Do you have some (easy) criterion that tells you how much of the input stream you have to read? Then you could read that much into a byte array and use that as the input for your reader.

Comment: Christian, even though I have changed my approach, I believe your idea to read in _x_ number of predetermined bytes into a byte array would be the best way to get around the issue I described. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You do not need to close a `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader` or probably most reader implementations, when you do not wish to close the underlying reader.

These readers do not hold any resources that a call to `close()` would make free and which the garbage collector would not make free anyway (e.g. native resources or values in static variables) when you drop the reference to the reader at the end of your method.

The underlying input streams that communicate with native resources, e.g. `FileInputStream` or streams obtained from URLs, must be closed to free those native resources.

For `Writer`, there's a difference in that `close()` usually calls `flush()`. But then, you can call `flush()` directly.

Comment: Yes, although some compression streams (though not `Readers` as far as I am aware) use native resources and need to be closed.

Comment: Indeed. So when you wanted to concatenate several output streams, each compressed by itself, into one output stream, one options is to override the close method as @Cristian C. suggests. (Something similar probably happens when using compressed archives containing several files.)

Answer (score 6):

### NoCloseInputStream

You might found this class in your classpath. Implementations are known from hibernate and  sun. If so, you could use this class as a wrapper. Good luck.

### CloseIgnoringInputStream

This one comes with apache-poi.

### CloseSuppressingInputStream

This one is from hibernate.

### KeepAliveInputStream

This one has a no-op close method too.

### StreamUtils.nonClosing() - Spring

From now it should be clear: Not closing a inputstream is a common requirement. This one comes from *spring*.

Thats all from my usual classpath.

Comment: I had tried my own class which extended the `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream` to ignore the close, but it didn't work. I tried the `CloseIgnoringInputStream` and it worked, their class extends the `FilterInputStream` so there must be some magic in there happening that I'm unaware of. Cheers!

Comment: I wished the ZipInputStream had an extra `getEntryInputStream` that behaves like this.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would just avoid the problem by changing the signature of your method to require that a BufferedReader (or Reader) be passed in.

Comment: This propagates the creation of the BufferedReader to the caller. But what if the calling method gets its stream from somewhere else, too?

Comment: You hava a good point: One might wish to provide a `Reader` based version, too. Because, if someone gets an `InputStream` with a non-default encoding, she cannot use the stream based method, because the InputStreamReader uses the wrong encoding.

Comment: The `java.util.Properties` class provides both `load(InputStream inStream)` and `load(Reader reader)` methods. I think having both options available to possible clients of your class is a convenience that can simplify the client code. That is, the client doesn't have to wrap an `InputStream` to get a `Reader` before passing it as an argument to the method.

Answer (score 3):

What I'd try would be overriding the [`close`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=es#ybd8S83PG4Q/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java&q=BufferedReader&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) method:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream)){
    public void close() throws IOException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (in == null)
                return;
        }
    }
};
// rest of your code
```

Kind of crazy, but it should work. Though, I'm not sure this is the best approach.

I think this is an interesting question, so I hope someone expert gives his/her opinion.

Comment: Why do you use the lock, if you don't do anything at all?